# Regular expression working in java failing in MySql

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying for an approximate match using regular expression against the supplied string.It is working fine in java but when i tried the approximate match in mysql using the regular expression support with the same sample which worked in java,says no match.In short the same sample worked in java but failed in mysql

```
public static void main(String a[]){ 
    if( "Java/myService/1,".matches("[[^,]+,]*Java/.*"))
        System.out.println("Pattern matched");
}
```

On executing the above code you will get "Pattern matched".

Here is MySql query which returns not match or '0'.

```
select 'Java/myService/1,' regexp '[[^,]+,]*Java/.*';
```

My understanding is ideally both should give a match for the specified example.Can any of you tell me why MySql match is failing here?Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you spell out the intended meaning of `[[^,]+,]*` for me please?

Comment: Please note that a correct interpretation of `[[^,]+,]` is "one of the characters `[^,]+,`".

Answer (score 0):

I guess with

```
"[[^,]+,]*Java/.*"
```

is meant:

```
"([^,]+,)*Java/.*"
```